# Is the sentence "Blood flows my veins" correct?

Tags: questions

I know you can say "Blood flows through my veins" but is my example also correct?

Comment: "Flow" is an intransitive verb...it doesn't take a direct object AFAIK.

Comment: With poetic license, it’s arguably grammatical. Its meaning, though, may be completely unrelated to the “flows in” version.

Comment: @Lawrence— I have always wondered as to what _poetic license_ really entails and, more so, what are its limits? I mean does any aberration from the course, justified or not, constitute _poetic license_?

Comment: @user405662 If nonstandard it comprehensible be, even Yoda or Tiggrish, poetically’s licensed.

Answer (score 1):

***Flow*** can be a transitive verb

> 1: to cause to flow
>
> - flowing oil over the swamp to kill mosquito larvae
>
> 2: to discharge in a flow
>
> - The new oil well flowed 100 barrels a day.

([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flow))

So, we could force the meaning and say that ***someone/something flows blood***. Look at this title of video on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pv5jUxKob9A):

> The Fountain that Flowed Blood and Water

(religious use)

Or, if you follow the second definition and example, you would need to have this construction: ***flow + quantity*** (where the quantity would be the object):

> flow rivers of blood
>
> Ex: The adversary ***flowed rivers of blood*** in the mainland. (I made this up, as the instances found online were too disturbing to paste here).

***My veins*** cannot be the object of the verb "flows".

Edit: I have found other transitive uses of ***flow*** not related to oil:

> Cryptography is the background of protecting ***the flowed information***
> between various communicated parties. ([Scholar Works](https://scholarworks.bridgeport.edu/xmlui/handle/123456789/1695)) (meaning that *various communicated parties flowed information among themselves*)

or

> The conference brochure used a image of a branded micro-chip embedded within a circuit board down ***which flowed information*** in the form of lights. ([Rogue Robot](https://www.roguerobot.co.uk/ministry-of-defence-project-breakdown/))